# std::map find() returning error

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile the below code in VS2015. The first version of my std::map is compiling, but the seconds version does not compile. Please let me know what I am doing wrong here..

```
std::map<int, std::string> _p;
typedef std::pair<int, std::string> _q;
_p.insert(_q(0, "Football0"));
_p.insert(_q(1, "Football1"));
std::string str = _p[1];    //OK...compiles and executes, no error, str = "Football1" as expected

std::map<int, DataDictionary> _p1;
typedef std::pair<int, DataDictionary> _q1;

DataDictionary dd1;
dd1.i = 0;
dd1.version = "ver1";
_p1.insert(_q1(0, dd1));

DataDictionary dd2;
dd2.i = 0;
dd2.version = "ver2";
_p1.insert(_q1(1, dd2));

DataDictionary DD = _p1.find[1];    //error C3867: 'std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::find': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
```

Even if I decide to change my std::map and use the following, I am getting the same error :

```
std::map<std::string, DataDictionary> _p1;
DataDictionary DD = _p1.find["1"]; //ERROR
```

I am trying to use map with the DataDictionary structure, and use `_p1.find["1"]` syntax to access the elements, as I am assuming that this approach will be faster than declaring iterator to the map, and then use find(). Please help. Thanks,

Comment: [`std::map::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) doesn't return the type you think it does.

Comment: You can use square brackets, the [*subscript operator*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at), or [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find), which is a normal function call so uses round brackets. You are mixing up both.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But please note that the code - std::string str = _p[1]; is actually working. Only when I am trying to return an struct instead of an std::string, I am getting compiler error

Comment: `_p[1]` is not the same thing as `_p.find[1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to use map with the DataDictionary structure, and use `_p1.find["1"]` syntax to access the elements

No, you are trying to use subscript operator on a member function:

`find("1")` would work.

`find["1"]` should not compile.

Consider using either `_p1.find("1")`, or `_p1["1"]`. The difference between them is that find returns <strike>a pair with a position in the map and a boolean flag</strike> an iterator (which may be past the end of the mapped sequence), and the subscript operator (`["1"]`) returns either a reference to the existing element, or it adds an element (if one is not found) and returns a reference to that.

To check if the map contains the key, use `if(_p1.count("1"))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant

```
_p1.find("1");
```

it returns an iterator to the found item.

use

```
std::map<std::string, DataDictionary>::iterator item = _p1.find("1");
```

or

in C++11 you can do

```
 auto item = _p1.find("1");
```

Comment: Thanks, but how the hell is the first version of the code - std::string str = _p[1]; is working. The only thing I am not able to understand is that...only when I am trying to return an struct instead of an std::string as the map value, I am getting the compiler error

Comment: @XMarshall why not? thats how you retrieved a value from a std::map. in your case `_p[1]` returns a value associated with  key `1`

Comment: @XMarshall `_p[1]` is using [`std::map::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at), something completely different than [`std::map::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find).

Comment: Thanks @WhozCraig, so probably my question should be why std::map::operator[] is working with std::string as value in the map. But when I am using a struct it is not working. Probably I need to provide the [] operator in my struct...

Comment: @XMarshall You need to use the `[]` operator - `DataDictionary DD = _p1[1];` - and not `find`. (The type of element is completely irrelevant.)

Comment: @XMarshall thats because there is no std::map::find[] in c++

Comment: @XMarshall Read *carefully* the two links I provided, and pay attention to the samples, which are *outstanding* on that site.

Comment: Thanks LorenceHernandez and WhozCraig, now I know my stupid mistake. )-:

Comment: Why would `find` return an allocator?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit i didnt say it returns an allocator, or you are not talking to me

Comment: @LorenceHernandez: No, you pointed out that it didn't, which is strange because nobody had suggested that it would. It's a completely random statement!